# ASP.Net Core/EF Core: Stack overflow after add-migration with many-to-many relationship between an Identity User class and a custom defined class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to configure many-to-many relationship between Knowledge and ApplicationUser classes. After 'add-migration' build succeeded, but I recieve stack overflow. I can't find any specific details on this issue.

```
    public class Question
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string QuestionString { get; set; }
        public  Knowledge Knowledge { get; set; }
    }
```

Identity user class

```
    public class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser
    {
        public virtual ICollection<UserKnowledge> Knowledges { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public class Knowledge
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string KnowledgeName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UserKnowledge> Users { get; set; }
    }
```

Joining entity class

```
    public class UserKnowledge
    {
         [Key]
         public int Id { get; set; }
         public string UserId { get; set; }
         [ForeignKey("UserId")]
         public  ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
         public int KnowledgeId { get; set; }
         [ForeignKey("KnowledgeId")]
         public  Knowledge Knowledge { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(): base()
        {}
    
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {}
    
        public DbSet<UserKnowledge> UserKnowledges { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Question> Questions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Knowledge> Knowledges { get; set; }
    
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
             modelBuilder.Entity<UserKnowledge>()
                  .HasKey(ub => ub.Id);
    
             modelBuilder.Entity<UserKnowledge>()
                  .HasOne(ub => ub.Knowledge)
                  .WithMany(u =>u.Users)
                  .HasForeignKey(ub => ub.KnowledgeId);
    
             modelBuilder.Entity<UserKnowledge>()
                  .HasOne(ub => ub.User)
                  .WithMany(u => u.Knowledges)
                  .HasForeignKey(ub => ub.UserId);
             modelBuilder.Entity<Knowledge>().HasKey(g => g.Id);
             modelBuilder.Entity<Knowledge>().HasMany(q => q.Questions).WithOne(q => q.Knowledge);
             modelBuilder.Entity<Question>().HasKey(g => g.Id);
                
                OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            }
        }
```

Can someone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: "I recieve stack overflow". Always include the actual error, as much as possible anyway.

Comment: I've replaced your .NET Framework tags (`[.net]`, `[asp.net]`, and `[entity-framework]`) tags with their .NET Core equivalents for you. Please ensure you read tag descriptions before using them to ensure that you use the correct tags. We understand your question through the tags you use and using the wrong tags gives us false information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concrete stack overflow issue is of course caused by the last line in `OnModelCreating` override, which calls itself

```
OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
```

It should instead call the base method

```
base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
```

and (unrelated) for `IdentityDbContext` derived classes it should be the first line before your own configuration, so you can override what it does if needed

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    // Your code goes here
}
```

Also unrelated, but when using custom identity entities, you should really inherit one of the generic `IdentityDbContext<...>` base classes with your entity type(s) passed as generic type arguments. In this case, `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    // ...
}
```

otherwise EF will treat the model as using [TPH (Table Per Hierarchy)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-hierarchy-and-discriminator-configuration) database inheritance strategy with discriminator column, which normally is not what you expect/want.